# How to make child z-index more than parent or any other way to achieve the effect?

Tags: html, css, z-index

[image: a]

I'm trying to develop the following effect. 
Where parents are two sections like this and child is an image. How to achieve this without using absolute?

```
<section>
  <img />
</section
<section>
  ..more content
</section>
```

But I got to know that child's z-index cannot be more than parent than whats the way round this?

Comment: So what have you tried so far to achieve this ? Please post HTML and CSS in a code snippet that reproduces your current situation

Answer (score 0):

`position: relative` and proper values of `bottom` and `left` on red parent will do the trick.
Also you can use `transform: translate(xValue, yValue)` to achieve the same effect.
Just remember to adjust `z-index` correctly.

Answer (score 0):

try keeping img tag out.

````
   </section>
   <img>
   <section class="section-2">
   </section>```

you can check this if it can work for you : 
try this fiddle


  https://jsfiddle.net/anviksuteiriy/d781L6ry/11/
````

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve that effect by using the default behaviour of nesting.

```
<div class="parent1">
  <div class="parent2">
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This layout will align the items as you requested, there is no need using `z-index`.

Comment: Section 2 can't be taken inside section 1